# Replace Character For All Rows using SQLAlchemy on Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, python-unicode

I made the mistake of accidentally using non-ascii characters in a form that was submitted into a database using SQLAlchemy, running on Flask.  Basically, rather than using the ASCII hyphen `–`, I used the unicode en-dash `–`.  I am trying to now go back and replace all occurrences of the en-dash with a hyphen in my database.

Let's say I have a users table, and the column I'm trying to change is called `occupation`.  I'm able to figure out which entries in my database have the invalid character, because when I run:

```
User.query.get(id)
```

if the user has an invalid ASCII character, it returns

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 167: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So how can I go about replacing all occurrences of the en-dash with a hyphen in the `occupation` column for all rows in my DB?

Comment: Have you tried doing something like this to perform queries? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819192/sqlalchemy-result-for-utf-8-column-is-of-type-str-why

Comment: Then you can just replace the en-dash in each record and persist the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by running a script over all entries in my database, and replacing the ones with faulty characters.

```
from user.models import *
for u in User.query.all():
    # \u2013 is unicode for en-dash
    if u"\u2013" in u.occupation:
        # replace with normal hyphen
        u.occupation = u.occupation.replace(u"\u2013", "-")
        db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the table is large, it may be more efficient perform the update as a single statement and  without retrieving any rows.  This could be done like this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
with Session.begin() as s:
    update = (
        sa.update(User)
        .where(User.occupation.contains('\N{en dash}'))
        .values(occupation=sa.func.replace(User.occupation, '\N{en dash}', '-'))
    )
    s.execute(update)
```